# chmod always unsets setgid bit on directories if I'm not in a group

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

Here's the scenario: I'm using Ubuntu Linux (12.10, if it matters), and I've got a directory whose permissions are thus:

```
drwxrws--- paul www-data    myfolder/
```

You can see the `setgid` bit is set. If I change any permissions on this folder (e.g., `chmod o+x myfolder`) it unsets the `setgid` bit.

According to `chmod`'s manpage:

> **chmod** preserves a directory's `set-user-ID` and `set-group-ID` bits unless you explicitly specify otherwise.

Elsewhere, it says that it unsets the `setgid` bit if the file's group doesn't match the user's effective group ID, but only on *regular* files (i.e., not folders). So, because my group is `paul` rather than `www-data`, I'd expect the above to happen if `myfolder/` were a regular file, but it ain't -- it's a directory.

So either I'm understanding the manual wrong, or `chmod` is not obeying its own instructions. Does anyone know which?

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the same section you already quoted from the manpage of `chmod`

> **SETUID AND SETGID BITS**
>
> [...]
>
> This behavior **depends on**
>   the policy and functionality of the **underlying chmod system call**.  When in doubt, 
>   check the underlying system behavior.

When tracing `chmod` it tries to set the setgid bit but the underlying `chmod()` system call ignores it.

```
fchmodat(AT_FDCWD, "b", 02755)          = 0
```

As you see `S_ISGID  (02000)` is set by the `chmod` command but not by the `chmod()` 
[here: `fchmodat()`] systemcall:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 me notmygrp 16 Mar 19 12:37 b
```

So the removal of the setgid bit is also true for directories if you are not member of the group.